# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, json

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CrudMvc.Models.RegistrationViewModelClass]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Message', line 1, position 11.

this is my RegistrationController class

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
   {
    // GET: Registration
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<RegistrationViewModelClass> regList;
        HttpResponseMessage responce = 
GlobalVariableClass.webapiclient.GetAsync("Registration").Result;
        regList = 
responce.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<RegistrationViewModelClass>> 
().Result;

        return View(regList);
    }
   }
```

this is my RegistrationViewModelClass

```
 public class RegistrationViewModelClass
  {

    public int Seqid { get; set; }
    public string roll_no { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
  }
```

i am getting Error on this line

```
regList = 
responce.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<RegistrationViewModelClass>> 
().Result;
```

Comment: The error message is very clear and descriptive. Can you explain what exactly is unclear about that message?

Comment: have you tried instead using `RegistrationViewModelClass[]` ?

Comment: Have a look at the actual JSON result from your HTTP call. Do you get an array of objects or a single object?

Comment: No, i am beginner in c# and have not more experience @Ehsan_Sajjad

Comment: i am getting single object @Onkel_Toob

Comment: if there is single object then, this should work : `ReadAsAsync<RegistrationViewModelClass>`

Comment: will you please write complete line @Ehsan_Sajjad